# Why do I get "403 You don't have permission to access this resource. " Error in Apache?

Tags: php, windows, apache

I am currently working on building a test API in pure oop PHP.
Everything was working fine but now when I try to call the GET for "/api.php::getfinantatori" I get an 403 forbidden error.

//code for api.php

```
<?php
require_once 'autoloader.php';
require_once 'classes/finantator.php';

// Handle API requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $apiEndpoint = '/api.php::';
    $commandPos = strpos($requestUri, $apiEndpoint) + strlen($apiEndpoint);

    if ($commandPos !== false) {
        $commandWithParams = substr($requestUri, $commandPos);
        list($command, $queryParams) = explode('?', $commandWithParams);
        parse_str($queryParams, $params);

        $finantatorAPI = new FinantatorAPI();

        switch ($command) {
            case 'getfinantatori':
                $finantatori = $finantatorAPI->getFinantatori();
                echo json_encode($finantatori);
                break;
            case 'getfinantatoribyparam':
                $filterFinantatorId = isset($params['finantatorId']) ? $params['finantatorId'] : null;
                $filterAbreviere = isset($params['abreviere']) ? $params['abreviere'] : null;
                $filterDescriere = isset($params['descriere']) ? $params['descriere'] : null;

                $filteredFinantatori = $finantatorAPI->getFinantatoriByFilter($filterFinantatorId, $filterAbreviere, $filterDescriere);
                echo json_encode($filteredFinantatori);
                break;
            default:
                http_response_code(400); // Bad Request
                echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Invalid command'));
        }
    }
}
```

//code for finantatori.php

```
<?php

class Finantator {
    public $finantatorId;
    public $abreviere;
    public $descriere;

    function __construct($finantatorId, $abreviere, $descriere) {
        $this->finantatorId = $finantatorId;
        $this->abreviere = $abreviere;
        $this->descriere = $descriere;
    }
}

class FinantatorAPI {
    private $data; // Array to hold the objects

    function __construct() {
        $this->data = $this->readDataFromCSV(); // Read data from CSV and populate the array
    }

    private function readDataFromCSV() {
        $data = array();

        // Replace 'path/to/your/csv/file.csv' with the actual path to your CSV file
        $csvFile = fopen('F:\xampp\htdocs\model\finantatori.csv', 'r');

        if ($csvFile !== false) {
            while (($dataRow = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== false) {
                // Assuming the CSV columns are in the order: finantatorId, abreviere, descriere
                $finantatorId = $dataRow[0];
                $abreviere = $dataRow[1];
                $descriere = $dataRow[2];

                $data[] = new Finantator($finantatorId, $abreviere, $descriere);
            }
            fclose($csvFile);
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function getFinantatori() {
        return $this->data;
    }


    public function getFinantatoriByFilter($filterFinantatorId = null, $filterAbreviere = null, $filterDescriere = null) {
        $filteredData = array();

        foreach ($this->data as $finantator) {
            if (($filterFinantatorId === null || $this->isWildcardMatch($filterFinantatorId, $finantator->finantatorId)) &&
                ($filterAbreviere === null || $this->isWildcardMatch($filterAbreviere, $finantator->abreviere)) &&
                ($filterDescriere === null || $this->isWildcardMatch($filterDescriere, $finantator->descriere))
            ) {
                $filteredData[] = $finantator;
            }
        }

        return $filteredData;
    }
    private function isWildcardMatch($filterValue, $actualValue) {
        return fnmatch($filterValue, $actualValue, FNM_CASEFOLD);
    }
}
```

I tried to workaround `.htacess` file adding `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^api.php-(.*)$ api.php?$1 [QSA,L]`  in it but no fix.

Comment: Why would you even use URIs like `file.php::something` instead of `file.php?action=something`? Try `RewriteRule ^api.php(.*)$ api.php?$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Specifically, `:` is the URL username/password separator. Don't use it in URLs _except_ for that purpose. Unless you explicitly use the hex-encoded equivalent, relying on the browser to treat it as "just a random character like everything else" is a losing strategy. Use proper URLs (which also means not exposing your server internals. so no URLs with `file.php` but URLs named for what they're for so that renaming your php script is a matter of updating your rewrite rules, not updating your entire website with 301/302's for the original URL)